# PD ExcelWriter Fails in Loops

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-excel

**pd ExcelWriter fails with >1 loops?**

I have code that works fine - outputs an Excel file and a .jpg - if I run it one pass, but the **Excel part doesn't work if I create a loop** and feed it >1 row in succession.

Every pass of create_outputs has different data going in. Every file has a different name. When I run it with multiple rows I don't get any Excel output, not the first file, not the last.

If I set a variable like "give me row 1", then change it to "give me row 2", etc etc, I get the outputs I want. But I have a bunch of these and that's tedious. I'm getting the JPGs I want. Why are the Excel files not writing?

BTW - I don't get any error feedback at all. It. Just. Doesn't. Work.

```
def create_outputs(data_in)
   ... save a .jpg
   ... create a .xlsx


for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if df.loc[index, 'mydata'] != '':
        create_outputs(df.loc[index, 'mydata'])
```

Comment: Please see how to create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your question is about ExcelWriter yet this is not used anywhere in the code you have provided. Also include a sample of `df`

Comment: Please provide the code in `create_outputs`